# Create a triangle out of stars using recursion

Tags: java

I first need to create a method called printStars that prints n stars in one line. For example, printStars(5) displays the line *****. **Using the printStars method**, write a method printTriangle that creates a triangle of stars. For example, printTriangle(5) should display:

*

**

(***

(****

(*****

In the second part you should modify your code so that it displays this:

(*****

(****

(***

**

*

Solution to the second part:

```
public static String printStars(int n) {
    if(n == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    return "*" + printStars(n - 1);
}
public static String printTriangle(int n) {
    if(n == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    return printStars(n) + "\n" + printTriangle(n - 1);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(printTriangle(7));
}
```

The reason I can not solve the first part is it requires you to use the printStars method, so I have no idea how I can recursion so that the number of stars increases each line.

Comment: It's the same question but this one requires you to use the printStars method

Comment: That would just print one star 5 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, first recurse in `printTriangle` and then `printStars`. Also, to prevent an empty line test for `n` equal to one. And prefer `System.lineSeparator()` over `\n`. Like,

```
public static String printTriangle(int n) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        return "";
    } else if (n == 1) {
        return printStars(1);
    }
    return printTriangle(n - 1) + System.lineSeparator() + printStars(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GFG{
    public static String printStars(int n) {
    if(n == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    return "*" + printStars(n - 1);
}
public static String printTriangle(int n) {
    if(n == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    return printStars(n) + "\n" + printTriangle(n - 1);
}
public static String printSimpleTriangle(int n, int i) {
    if(n<i) {
        return "";
    }
    return printStars(i) + "\n" + printSimpleTriangle(n, i+1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(printTriangle(7));
    System.out.println(printSimpleTriangle(7,1));
}
}
```